# Adding a legend to CARTO.js v4 map application

Tags: javascript, carto, legend, carto-js

I have made a map that shows fire risk for the different Districts within South Africa, and each fire risk is styled by value to match a certain color. I am trying to add a legend to show what each colour relates to a field (extreme, high, medium or low-risk level) but I am not having any luck. There is [this legend example](https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/examples/#example-legends) on the CARTO docs, but it is a little tricky to adapt to my code.

I have added the [code and a CodePen](https://codepen.io/JonoGIS/pen/WKNOqE), and here are the layer properties:

[image]

`overall` is the column I would like to represent in the legend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. I've created a diff to show you the places where you need to make some adjustments.
[Code diff with the explanation](https://github.com/ivanmalagon/cartojs-legend-issue/pull/1/files)

1. You didn't have the style for painting the circles. Added to the CSS.
2. Your cartoCSS asked for a ramp on `polygon-fill` but you were then asking for `marker-fill` metadata, I guess based on our examples that are based on point instead of polygons.
3. While traversing the categories, you need to go through the category name.

[There you have a clone of you codepen working](https://codepen.io/hacheka/pen/Epayav)

Regards.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Ivan! I really appreciate the extra info to show me where I was going wrong, I just learnt so much. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You should get the building blocks from the docs example. First of all, you need to add a legend container:

```
<!-- legend -->
<div id="legend">
  <h1>Legend</h1>
  <div id="legend-content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Then after adding your basemap and layer, you should add a js script similar to this one:

```
const legend = $("#legend-content");

layer.on('metadataChanged', renderCategoryLegend);

function renderCategoryLegend(metadata){
  console.log(metadata);
  metadata.styles.forEach(function (styleMetadata) {
    if (styleMetadata.getProperty() == 'marker-fill') {
        let categories = styleMetadata.getCategories();
        console.log(categories)
        for (category of categories){
          legend.append(`<li><div class="circle" style="background:${category.value}"></div> ${category.name}</li>`)
      }
    }
  });
}
```

First, get the legend container. Secondly, assign a function that renders the legend when the metadata changes. Third, this function gets the metadata information, get the categories from the `marker-fill` ramp and append an element with the name and color.

[Here](https://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/3000c714aac5a44b290b73b436601a34) is the whole code.

[image]